# How to Insert parameter from Concurrent Program(.prog file) into a table using sql*loader control file created dynamically

Tags: bash, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper, sql-loader

I have the .prog file from a host program created in oracle apps. I am sending a parameter from oracle apps with host program and I can access it in the .prog file like this e.g.

`echo "5 Concurrent Program Parameter 1      : " ${5}`

I need to use this parameter ($5) into the control file (.ctl) where I will insert some columns and this parameter into a new table. e.g

```
LOAD DATA
INSERT INTO TABLE TABLE_NAME
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"'
TRAILING NULLCOLS
(
COL1,
COL2,
DATA_FROM_PROG (5) => ** here i need to insert that data from the .prog file**
)
```

I am thinking it would have to be included in this command somehow so it creates this control file or another dynamically but I can't figure out how to send that parameter and make this work.
I am familiar with this line that I used in the past for simpler problems

e.g.`sqlldr userid=user/pass data=$5 control=control.ctl`

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using Bash Script in the .prog file to create the control file (.ctl) dynamically from scratch seems to be working and I can use the parameters as well.
So in the .prog file we would have:

```
echo "5 Concurrent Program Parameter 1      : " ${5} /*this is only to test it*/

/* *Printf* with *>* command will create and edit a file.
Alternative *Printf* with *>>* would append to the file*/

printf "LOAD DATA\n
INFILE 'path_to_csv_file.csv'\n /*this is data for col1, col2 etc*/
INSERT INTO TABLE TABLE_NAME\n
FIELDS TERMINATED BY \',\' OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY \'\"\'\n
TRAILING NULLCOLS\n
(COL1,\n
COL2,\n
DATA_FROM_PROG CONSTANT ${5})" > [name and path to control file (e.g./folder/control.ctl)]
```

This way, when the .prog file is executed it will Dynamically create the .ctl file which will have the parameter that we want (${5}).
And we can also add something like this to run the .ctl file

```
sqlldr userid=user/pass control=[path_to_control]control.ctl log=track.log
```

Also make sure to escape the quotes `'` and double quotes `"` with `\` because you will get some errors otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't know, as I don't know anything about Oracle apps. nor ".prog" files.

Workaround - from my perspective - would be to

- load only known data (from the source file)
- `data_from_prog` would be specified as a **filler** field (and populated with `NULL` values (if `trailing nullcols` is specified))
- after loading session is over, **update** that column from Oracle apps. - then you'd use a simple `update` statement; you're in (PL/)SQL *world*, it is easy to write such a query (at least, I hope so)

Comment: I understand what you mean but it wouldn’t work for me because in this case I have to follow the instructions for this.There are more ways to do this indeed, What I’m looking for would involve using bash scripting to edit the .cvs file from the .prog. Thanks anyway!

Comment: No problem; I hope you'll make it work, eventually. Good luck!